# Select size for output vector with 1000s of labels

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

Most of the examples on the Internet regarding `multi-label` image classification are based on just a `few` labels. For example, with `6` classes we get:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layer=base)
model.add(layer=layers.Flatten())
model.add(layer=layers.Dense(units=256, activation="relu"))
model.add(layer=layers.Dense(units=6, activation="sigmoid"))
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg16 (Model)                (None, 7, 7, 512)         14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               6422784   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 1542      
=================================================================
Total params: 21,139,014
Trainable params: 13,503,750
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
```

However, for datasets with `significantly` more labels, the size of the training `parameters` explodes and eventually training process fails with a `ResourceExhaustedError` error. For example, with `3047` label we get:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layer=base)
model.add(layer=layers.Flatten())
model.add(layer=layers.Dense(units=256, activation="relu"))
model.add(layer=layers.Dense(units=3047, activation="sigmoid"))
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg16 (Model)                (None, 7, 7, 512)         14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               6422784   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3047)              783079    
=================================================================
Total params: 21,920,551
Trainable params: 14,285,287
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
_________________________________________________________________
```

Obviously, there is something wrong with my network but not sure how to overcome this issue...

Comment: I'm supposing you are using an ImageDataGenerator? for VGG with a lot of training sample, it's also a good idea to use a GPU accelerator

Comment: @MarcoCerliani You guessed right, I am using `ImageDataGenerator`! As you can see on my answer bellow, I managed to keep training going by reducing `batch` size (from `1024` to `256`) which is a good thing, however, given the fairly large machine on AWS (`p2.xlarge` with 61 GB RAM and 11 GB GPU) I would expect that resources are not an issue. Could you please elaborate what you mean by `GPU accelerator`? Should I use a bigger machine or maybe use a different model? Do you see any obvious problem with my transfer-learning model overall?

Answer (score 0):

Resource Exhauseted Error is related to memory issues. Either you don't have enough memory in your system or some other part of the code is causing memory issues.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the `try/except` and then `debugged` the error: `OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1024,64,224,224]` where `1024` was my batch size. I reduced batch size to `256` and training was able to start. This is a bit weird though cause I am using a fairy large machine on AWS `p2.xlarge` (61 GB of RAM and 11 of GPU). Do you notice anything else strange based on you experience?

Comment: 1024 is a very high batch size. you should have started as low as 32 or 64 and then increase it based on your available GPU.

Comment: I got it, thank you. Network-wise, do you see any strange set-up? I mean, does it make sense that I go from Flatten of output shape 25088, to Dense of output shape 256, and then again to another Dense output shape of size 3047? Does this "progression" make sense?

Comment: Its called a bottleneck architecture, commonly used in autoencoders. There is no "perfect way" for structuring your model. You have to experiment yourself and find the suitable architecture for your data